# Sandbox: bash(72986) deny(1) file-write-data /Users/XXX/ios/Pods/resources-to-copy-XXXShareExtension.txt

Tags: ios, react-native

Xcode build Share extension error for react native.

```
Sandbox: bash(72986) deny(1) file-write-data /Users/XXX/ios/Pods/resources-to-copy-XXXShareExtension.txt
```

I have tried to rebuild many times and still get an error........

Answer (score 162, accepted):

update your Xcode project build option 'ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING' to 'No'.

[image: Operation path reference]

Comment: This seem to be the only solution when React native ios build script runs into perssion to read and write file issues.

Comment: It didnot work for me.

Answer (score 8):

### Sandbox: swiftlint(33399) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/Your Name/Your Projects/Pods/SwiftLint/swiftlint - Xcode 15 Xcode 15.1

This error indicates that SwiftLint does not have permissions to read the specified file. To resolve such an error, you can follow these steps:

- Check the file permissions in the Terminal using the following command:

`ls -l /Users/Your Name/Your Projects/Pods/SwiftLint/swiftlint`

If the file has limited permissions or lacks read permission, you may need
to adjust the permissions.

- Update the Sandboxing Option:

Navigate to Targets -> Project -> Build Settings -> Choose (All and Combined) -> User Script Sandboxing. Change the option from "Yes" to "No".

OR

Search 'ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING'

[sandbox error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1F58.png)

Answer (score 3):

This solution works also for ionic projects for the error: deny(1) file-read-data

> update your Xcode project build option 'ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING'
> to 'No'.

[image: path]