# Xcode Sandbox Permission Denied Error with CocoaPods on Specific Project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I keep receiving the following errors when I run previews or builds of my App

```
error: Sandbox: rsync.samba(3328) deny(1) file-write-create /Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TESTER-hbrfsmbquzqcrpfrhpzcnelekwor/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/TESTER/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TESTER.app/Frameworks/ScrollCounter.framework/_CodeSignature (in target 'TESTER' from project 'TESTER')

error: Sandbox: rsync.samba(3329) deny(1) file-write-create /Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TESTER-hbrfsmbquzqcrpfrhpzcnelekwor/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/TESTER/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TESTER.app/Frameworks/ScrollCounter.framework/.Info.plist.dyIsUH (in target 'TESTER' from project 'TESTER')

error: Sandbox: rsync.samba(3329) deny(1) file-write-create /Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TESTER-hbrfsmbquzqcrpfrhpzcnelekwor/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/TESTER/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TESTER.app/Frameworks/ScrollCounter.framework/.ScrollCounter.p9bsAO (in target 'TESTER' from project 'TESTER')
```

I just implemented a CocoaPods library called ScrollCounter into it, I have used it before and have it in other projects and it works fine - but now when I try and implement it and then preview my code I get the following sandbox errors.

I've cleaned the build folder, I've started another new project and reinstalled the Pods - my podfile is the same as my other working one (Yes I changed the targets). But no dice. Very confused as to why it works on another project but not in this one and any other that I try and start.

Tried this and had no luck

```
 chmod -R 755 /Users/myname/Documents/TESTER
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sandbox: bash(72986) deny(1) file-write-data /Users/XXX/ios/Pods/resources-to-copy-XXXShareExtension.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76792138/sandbox-bash72986-deny1-file-write-data-users-xxx-ios-pods-resources-to-co)

Comment: Yep, probably visualises it better than my response below.

Answer (score 8):

Setting User Script Sandboxing to No in the PROJECT > BUILD SETTINGS > BUILD OPTIONS was how I resolved this. New to Stack Overflow wasn't sure if you are meant to respond to your own questions.

Also I found that my other project which I push to an online git repo doesn't have the USER Script sandboxing option - I don't know why, but that is why the other file worked.

Comment: Answering your own question is fine and welcome if it solves your issue. Well done!

Comment: Nice. Yes, I found the Same. I found it had to be under "App", not under "Pods" or similar which I was looking at.